# How can I tell Active Directroy to pass the computer name into each users attribute?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

When i googled a bit i came uppon this code for a similar situation.

```
$user = "user"
$manager = Get-Aduser $user -Properties manager | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Manager
Switch -wildcard ($manager){
    "*Manager Name*" {Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Replace @{extensionAttribute4="Bagelphobia"} -WhatIf}
}
```

Now my question would be if someone knew of a way to adapt this so that the Computer name will be passed into a custom attribute of the User. Computer owners are written in the description, so i thought this might be used to specify to which account the pc is linked.

Also how would you run such a script?

[picture of the description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWikL.png)

Comment: "Computer owners are written in the description" - can you show an example of such a description?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I added a screenshot

Comment: Then you need to use `Get-ADComputer` and iterate over that collection. For each (live) computer, read the owner name from the Description property and the use `Get-ADUser` to try and find that user. Once you have that user object, you can set the computername into some user attribute.

Comment: @Theo would it be possible to give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not explain which custom user atribute you will be using to store the computername, and also if one user can own multiple computers,
below code is assuming one user can be the owner of just one computer. If that is not the case, please explain the attribute you're using: its name and type (a string? a multivalued property or?)

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties Description | ForEach-Object {
    $computerName = $_.Name         # just for convenience
    $ownerName    = $_.Description
    # Try and find the AD user mentioned in the Description property of the computer
    # Format seems to be Surname GivenName
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($ownerName)) {
        $lastname, $firstname = ($ownerName -split '\s+', 2).Trim()
        $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "GivenName -eq '$firstname' -and Surname -eq '$lastname'"
        if ($user) {
            Write-Host "Adding '$computerName' to user $($user.Name)"
            # You didn't say which custom attribute the computername should go to, 
            # so change example 'extensionAttribute1' here
            $user | Set-ADUser -Replace @{ extensionAttribute1 = $computerName} 
        }
        else {
            Write-Warning "Could not find user '$ownerName'"
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Computer $computerName does not have a Description filled in"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
$co=@{} # computer-owners
get-adcomputer -ldapfilter '(ManagedBy=*)' -properties ManagedBy |select name,ManagedBy|foreach {$m=get-aduser $_.ManagedBy|select -ExpandProperty samaccountname; if($co.ContainsKey($m)){$co[$m]+=$_.name}else{$co.add($m,@($_.name))}}
$users=$co.Keys|Get-ADUser -Properties extensionattribute4 
foreach($u in $users) {
    $ext = "Associated computers: {0}" -f ($co[$u.samaccountname] -join ", ")
    if($u.extensionattribute4 -ne $ext) {
        set-aduser -Identity $u.samaccountname -Replace @{'extensionattribute4'=$ext} -WhatIf
    }

}
```

In this script you will have the associated computers written to a custom attribute of the user.
Note that I changed to reading from `ManagedBy` instead of `Description`. I wouldn't trust `Description` to point to a user. `ManagedBy` on the other hand would be more sane.